# How to determine the order of passed keyword arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing

### Problem:

I want to write a general purpose function:

```
def foo(positional, a=None, b=None, c=None, *, keyword_only=True):
    # ... ?? ... magic_code
    return a_b_c_in_tuple_in_order
```

that returns a tuple retaining the order of keyword arguments `a,b,c`:

```
xx = 'some object'
>>> foo(xx, 1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
>>> foo(xx, 1, 2)
(1, 2)
>>> foo(xx, a=1, b=2, c=3, keyword_only=False)
(1, 2, 3)
>>> foo(xx, b=2, a=1, c=3)   # <---- key behaviour
(2, 1, 3)
>>> foo(xx, b=2, c=3)
(2, 3)
>>> foo(xx, c=3, a=1)
(3, 1)
>>> foo(xx, a='may be anything', c=range(5), b=[1, 2])
('may be anything', range(0, 5), [1, 2])
>>> foo(xx, b=1)
(1,)    # may be 1 or (1,)
```

How can I achieve this? Is such a code unpythonic, and if yes, what should I use instead?

Primary objectives are easy usage and readability.

### Why?

My aim is to use such a function for conversions between unit systems (e.g. SI <--> imperial, but actual use case is more advanced), where the user would be able to intuitively write e.g.

```
l, (t1, t2) = convert(params, lengths=L, times=(T1, T2), normalized=True)
# or
(t1, t2), l = convert(params, times=(T1, T2), lengths=L, normalized=True)
```

regardless of how the function is defined, and if the quantities are floats, arrays, etc.

### Corner cases:

Responding well to such misusages are not required, but being fool-proof is a bonus:

```
>>> foo(b=2, a=1, c=3, positional=xx)
(2, 1, 3)
>>> foo(b=2, positional=xx, a=1, keyword_only=False, c=3)
(2, 1, 3)
```

Comment: How is the user using these tuples?
It is more pythonic to return a dict of these values because keyword/named arguments are not ordered. They can be passed in any order. A more pythonic return would be:
`{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}` and then the user choses what to do with the values stored in each of those keys. Why does the order matter to your users here?

Comment: @spacether the usage would be what is described in the *Why?** section. I want the return values to be unpackable, so the entire conversion is done within one easily readable line.

Comment: `for conversions` is a bit vague. What do you do with the tuples after you have them? Do you not need to know the argument names corresponding to the values?

Comment: @spacether oh sorry, you're right. I meant conversions between different metric units (e.g. SI - imperial, but actual use case is more complicated).

Comment: Actually if you are looking for unit conversions, astropy has a pretty powerful and roboust implementation which is [described here](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/units/), and also the source is [here](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/tree/master/astropy/units). In my opinion it is a much better way than relying on the order of keyword arguments, so it might turn out to be useful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@rdas almost had it
Using their answer as a decorator preserves the original function signature and gives you the data that you want:

```
kwargs_to_extract = {'a', 'b', 'c'}

def kwarg_tuple_returner(fn):
    def tuple_extractor(positional, *args, **kwargs):
        _unused_return = fn(positional, *args, **kwargs)
        if args and kwargs:
            return args + tuple(v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in kwargs_to_extract)
        if args:
            return args
        if kwargs:
            return tuple(v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in kwargs_to_extract)

    return tuple_extractor

@kwarg_tuple_returner
def foo(positional, a=None, b=None, c=None, *, keyword_only=True):
    # ... ?? ... magic_code
    # nothing below matters because we return our argument value from our decorator
    a = "mangled"
    b = 5
    c = 3.14
    return None

xx = 'obj'

print(foo(xx, 1, 2, 3))
print(foo(xx, 1, 2))
print(foo(xx, a=1, b=2, c=3, keyword_only=False))
print(foo(xx, b=2, a=1, c=3))
print(foo(xx, b=2, c=3))
print(foo(xx, c=3, a=1))
print(foo(xx, a='may be anything', c=range(5), b=[1, 2]))
print(foo(xx, b=1))
print(foo(b=2, a=1, c=3, positional=xx))
print(foo(b=2, positional=xx, a=1, keyword_only=False, c=3))
print(foo(xx, 1, c=2))
```

Results in:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 3)
(3, 1)
('may be anything', range(0, 5), [1, 2])
(1,)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 1, 3)
(1, 2)
```

Comment: +1 because it's a neat way to preserve function signature. Problem is decreased code readability (and somewhat hacky code), since the entire function is now inside the decorator, and the function itself can't do anything with the values. Every such function would need it's own specific decorator.

Comment: Would you need to do this change on many functions? The function foo can do something with the values, we pass them through. In your problem statement you show us returning tuples back inside foo, so you already require us to have the output of foo be tuples.

Comment: I just meant this approach moves the entire function definition into a decorator, and the actual definition itself becomes merely a placeholder.

Comment: But the code is a good answer nevertheless. FWIW in my (scientific) code I'd define a bunch of these to convert between some (arbitrarily normalized) unit systems. I didn't include this in the question in hope of a general answer. Maybe I should've included that the code (of course) would change the values according to which argument they were passed in.

Comment: So we didn't move the entire function into the decorator, just the tuple extraction and returning. Don't we need to run foo so we execute `# ... ?? ... magic_code` in foo?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to pass all your examples, though I'm not sure what the behaviour of `positional` & `keyword_only` should be:

```
def foo(positional, *args, **kwargs):
    if args and kwargs:
        return args + tuple(v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in {'a', 'b', 'c'})
    if args:
        return args
    if kwargs:
        return tuple(v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in {'a', 'b', 'c'})

xx = 'obj'

print(foo(xx, 1, 2, 3))
print(foo(xx, 1, 2))
print(foo(xx, a=1, b=2, c=3, keyword_only=False))
print(foo(xx, b=2, a=1, c=3))
print(foo(xx, b=2, c=3))
print(foo(xx, c=3, a=1))
print(foo(xx, a='may be anything', c=range(5), b=[1, 2]))
print(foo(xx, b=1))
print(foo(b=2, a=1, c=3, positional=xx))
print(foo(b=2, positional=xx, a=1, keyword_only=False, c=3))
print(foo(xx, 1, c=2))
```

Result:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 3)
(3, 1)
('may be anything', range(0, 5), [1, 2])
(1,)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 1, 3)
(1, 2)
```

It relies on the fact that dictionaries in python3 are ordered.

Comment: This ruins the signature of `foo` and doesn't work with `print(foo(xx, 1, c=2))`

Comment: For what it's worth, preserving the ordering of keyword arguments is guaranteed separately from the order-preserving dicts, although this was helped by the order-preserving dicts. See PEP 468.

Comment: I'd have been happier (readibility) if I could explicitly define the argument variables. But according to ruhola's comments that seems inpossible, so this is the best possible way. I wait for a bit for if someone figures it out though.

Comment: @ruohola True. At the same time, that is more fitting in the mis-use category TBH. The ruined signature is more painful, but I can rolll with that compromise.